How to merge with Apache POI and keep spacing and formatting
  XMLSlideShow ppt = new XMLSlideShow();
        // Creating an empty presentation
        if (!powerpoints.isEmpty()) {

            for (String arg : powerpoints) {

                FileInputStream inputstream = new FileInputStream(arg);

                XMLSlideShow src = new XMLSlideShow(inputstream);

                ppt.setPageSize(src.getPageSize());

                for (XSLFSlide srcSlide : src.getSlides()) {

                    ppt.createSlide().importContent(srcSlide);

                }
                src.close();
                inputstream.close();
            }
            String mergedFile = intropath + "PowerPoints/result1.pptx";
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(mergedFile);
            ppt.write(out);
            ppt.close();
            out.close();

I am attempting to merge powerpoints with this code. It merges all the powerpoints for the most part. Some spacing is off though and every time I open the result powerpoint it says it "needs to be repaired". Any way to fix both of these issues or alternate ways? I used to use Aspose Slides cloud but it has been giving me issues lately.

This "needs to be repaired" error may be caused by a corruption or error in the XML files, it may be due to the combined presentations being in different formats, or the slide layout may not be working properly.To preserve the Slide Layout, you can follow like this in the for loop.
for (XSLFSlide srcSlide : src.getSlides()) {
XSLFSlideLayout srcLayout = srcSlide.getSlideLayout();
XSLFSlide newSlide = ppt.createSlide(srcLayout);
//...


Exception in thread "main" org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.OpenXML4JRuntimeException: Rule M2.4 exception : Part '/_rels/.rels' not found - this error should NEVER happen!
Check that your code is closing the open resources in the correct order prior to filing a bug report.
If you can provide the triggering file, then please raise a bug at https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/enter_bug.cgi?product=POI and attach the file that triggers it, thanks!
This is what i get with that code
